# How to fetch a method name from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

Lets say I have a list of strings with different method names, lets consider one-element list:

```
list = [split]
```

Is there any way to fetch the method name from the list when I want to use it? I'll give an exmple below, which doesn't work for me:

```
string = 'This is a string'
splitted_string = string.list[0]()
```

When I run the code, it's giving me:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list'

Comment: "Is there any way to fetch the method name" - yes, `list[0].__name__`. No, it's not possible to call it with that syntax.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have and what you want to do? What is ``split``? Did you mean ``list = ["split"]``? Do you want to call ``string.split()``, where the ``split`` is read from ``list``?

Comment: I'm trying to deal with a problem where the input I'm given contains a names of different methods. I've been able to extract those methods and put them in the list: 
`methods = ['intersection_update', 'update', 'symmetric_difference_update', 'difference_update']`
Then I have a set A and a nested list called elements like so:
`elements = [['2', '3', '5', '6', '8', '9', '1', '4', '7', '11'], ['55', '66'], ['22', '7', '35', '62', '58'], ['11', '22', '35', '55', '58', '62', '66']]`
I was hoping that I could write a for loop that would apply a method and a corresponding sublist of elements

Comment: Are you aware that methods are first class? You can put in a list and iterate over them directly.

Comment: I've already solved the problem, the getattr function was the key for me. Thanks for the help!